# Smarty extends not works

Tags: php, smarty, extends

My inheritance in Smarty doesn't work,

These are the template files:

./views/parent.tpl
  ./views/modules/child.tpl

So this is my child.tpl =

```
/* child.tpl */
{extends file='../parent.tpl'}
{block name='contents_accueil'}

<article>
<p>Something here</p>
</article>

{/block}
```

And my parent.tpl :

```
<div>
<p>Something else</p>
   {block name='contents_accueil'}{/block}
</div>
```

Why does it not work? It does not include my child.tpl file.

Thanks

The file php which calls the parent.tpl

```
require_once('application/librairies/tpl/Smarty.class.php');
require_once('config.inc.php');

$data=array();
$smarty=new Smarty();

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $current_page=$_GET['page'];
} 

$data = (isset($current_page)) ? $_PAGES[$current_page] : $data=HOME_PAGE;

$smarty->assign('data', $data);
$smarty->display('./application/views/parent.tpl');
```

Comment: block name should be quoted and `{extends file='../layout.tpl'}` goes to layout.tpl instead of parent.tpl

Comment: I edited it but don't works

Comment: what error(s) you get?

Comment: Show us the php code calling the template ($smarty->display)

Comment: I edited my post with the file php. I don't have error, just the child.tpl doesn't seems to appear

Comment: `$smarty->display('./application/views/parent.tpl');` you have to display the child.tpl (not parent)

Comment: My parent is a layout which include the child. So i must display the layout(parent) which include the child dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sofl said, you got smarty template inheritance wrong. You have to display the child.tpl, not the parent, because the parent can be used for multiple childs, i.e. child2.tpl will look like:

```
{extends file='../parent.tpl'}
{block name='contents_accueil'}

<article>
<p>Something completely different here</p>
</article>

{/block}
```

As you see, childs are the only ones that have all the information. If you just display parent.tpl, smarty doesn't have any clue about what file use as child. Think of {extends} as a container include